# Summary Error Configuring HAProxy via pfSense

Tags: routing, haproxy, pfsense

I configured a frontend record that is refering to a backend server pool with one record. The referred HAProxy Backend server pool contains a single record with the **Max con** value set to **2000**.

In the Statistics report I can see statistics of these rules and everythings looks fine, except that gray Backend row with aggregated values contains the value 200 for Sessions Limit, while the single row above this one has the value of 2000 (as configured in the server pool record).

Testing also yields a result of 200 sessions max. What could be the problem? Do I need to restart the server pool of is there something else I am missing?